# How to determine how dead a HDD is from SMARTCTL report

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I had a random report in an open Terminal today saying that "My hard drive is about to fail!"

I did some tests and I'm not sure how bad this is. The computer is acting fine but I went ahead and pushed all my work to github. I don't want to continue working on this computer if there is a chance it'll just crash and I'll lose everything.

The drive is an HDD - Western Digital Caviar SE Serial ATA

What should a normal smartctl look like for a stable drive?

SMART Attributes:

[image]

Test Fails:

[image]

Comment: Are you really talking about a SSD? Especially the `Spin_Up_Time` surprises me in the context of SSDs.

Comment: Yeah it's apparently not. I got the drive lettering confused at the time. I have 5+ drives connected to this machine and they all have similar sizes.

Comment: Please update your question accordingly, then also DavidPostill's answer fits to the question.

Comment: @mpy Done. David's answer seems to be fine without any edits.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### I did some tests and I'm not sure how bad this is

**Short Answer:**

Backup this drive and replace **immediately**.

**Long Answer:**

A company called [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com/) has collected data on hard drive failures. It has released that data in company blogs, highlighting which manufacturer's drives failed more often than others.

In a [recent blog](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-smart-stats/) it published data indicating exactly which 5 SMART attributes indicate imminent drive failure:

> From experience, we have found the following 5 SMART metrics indicate impending disk drive failure:
>
> - SMART 5 – Reallocated_Sector_Count.
> - SMART 187 – Reported_Uncorrectable_Errors.
> - SMART 188 – Command_Timeout.
> - SMART 197 – Current_Pending_Sector_Count.
> - SMART 198 – Offline_Uncorrectable.
>
> We chose these 5 stats based on our experience and input from others
> in the industry because they are consistent across manufacturers and
> they are good predictors of failure.

The article goes on to suggest:

```
SMART 5: Reallocated_Sector_Count
1-4 keep an eye on it, more than 4 replace

SMART 187: Reported_Uncorrect
1 or more replace

SMART 188: Command_Timeout
1-13 keep an eye on it, more than 13 replace

SMART 197: Current_Pending_Sector_Count
1 or more replace

SMART 198: Offline_Uncorrectable
1 or more replace
```

In your case 5 (raw value 2), 197 (raw value 484) and 198 (raw value 371) are showing signs of failure.